# Get code through strings in java

Tags: java, string, int

Explanation:

if the input string is 'hello worlds', output will be 2.

Length of the word "hello" = 5

Length of the word "worlds" = 6

add their length to get total length = 5+6 = 11

which is not a single digit, so continuously add all digits till we get single digit i.e. 1+1=2
Therefore, the single digit is = 2 (as answer/output).

I tried with my code as follows:

```
import java.util .*;

class Codestring {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter word");
        String word = sc.nextLine();
        int len2 = 0, len1 = 0, count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (word.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                len2 = count;
                System.out.println(len2);
                count = 0;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
        len1 = count;
        System.out.println(len1);
        int c = len1 + len2;
        System.out.println(c);

        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        do {
            array.add(c % 10);
            c /= 10;
        }
        while (c > 0);
        System.out.println(array);

        while (array.size() >= 2) {
            array = reduce(array);
            return array;
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<Integer> reduce(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            array = array[i] + array[i + 1];
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

I reached to my output as:

Enter word

hello worlds

5

6

11

[1, 1]

Comment: Kindly format your code

Comment: Please indent your code properly. I don't want to image how many compilations errors you can have .. please use an IDE, for ex you can't do array[i] on a List which is not an array*

Comment: So why did you stop there and only return the array? Just sum up the items and you're done.

Comment: The method sould be simply : read line of input, split from spaces in String[], chnge to int[] where you put the length, then sum

Comment: The code has compilation errors . Where have you defined variable `c`.

Comment: Also your solution is not generic at all, it works well for only 2 words, not more

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that might answer your question

```
import java.util .*;
class Codestring {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter word");
        String word = sc.nextLine();
        String strSplits[] = word.split(" ");
        int length = 0;

        for (String strTmp : strSplits) {
            System.out.println("Word: " + strTmp + ", Length: " + strTmp.length());
            length += strTmp.length();
        }
        System.out.println("Total words: " + strSplits.length);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Consolidated Length: " + reduce(length));
        sc.close();
    }

    public static long reduce(long length) {
        while (length > 9) {
            System.out.println("Initial Length: " + length);
            long y = 0, factor = 1;
            // go through each digit from the bottom and calc the diff.
            while (length > 9) {
                y += factor * Math.abs(length % 10 - length / 10 % 10);
                length /= 10;
                // each digit is worth 10x the last.
                factor *= 10;
            }
            length = y;
        }
        return length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public int digit(int num)
    {
    int s=0;
        
    while(num>0)
    {
        int r=num%10;
        s+=r;
        num=num/10;
    }
    
    if(s>9)
    {
    s=digit(s);
    }
   return s;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String input1=sc.nextLine();
    String a[]=input1.split("\\s");
    int num=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        int n=a[i].length();
        num+=n;
    }
    Main ob=new Main();
   int n=ob.digit(num);
   System.out.println(n);
}
```

SIMPLE METHOD TO SOLVE THIS :).IN this we first add the length of the string and then add that sum up to a single digit.